# How to customize camera preview in framelayout

Tags: android, xml, camera

Im trying to copy exact xml layout of this scanner. But it gives me a hard time to do it. I've search and tell that it would need surfaceview to create it.

[image]

Current xml output

[image]

my activity_camera.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffff"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1"
tools:context="com.example.administrator.myapplication.CameraTestActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.11"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="170dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="170dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="Hello! - "
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="76dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="76dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="#ffff"
    android:text="Sign-out"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.07"
    android:text="ASEC MOBILE SCANNER"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/scanText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.07"
    android:text="Scanning..."
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="30sp"></TextView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="245dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/cameraPreview"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/gray_btn_bg_color"
        android:visibility="visible">


    </FrameLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/cameraPreview"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cameraPreview"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/cameraPreview"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cameraPreview"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Client want the design to look like it. I'm using frameLayout.

Comment: Maybe using some external library would help you. For example: 
https://github.com/dlazaro66/QRCodeReaderView

Comment: Is there any other way to customize my xml layout to look like it? using frame layout that i use?